# Is there a simpler way to exclude fields from mobx makeAutoObservable in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx

I am migrating a view model class from plain javaScript to typeScript.

In javaScript I could call `makeAutoObservable` and AFTER that define additional fields that need to be non-observable, and that worked just fine:

```
class List {

    constructor(notifier, apiClient) {
        makeAutoObservable(this)

        // Things below will not become observable

        this.notifier = notifier
        this.apiClient = apiClient
        this.loadOperation = LoadOperation(this.executeLoad, { onError: this.loadFailed })
        this.textFilter = TextFilter()
        this.showInactiveFilter = ShowInactiveFilter()
        this.sorter = Sorter()
        this.pager = Pager()
        this.orchestrator = Orchestrator({
            loadOperation: this.loadOperation,
            filters: [this.textFilter, this.showInactiveFilter],
            sorter: this.sorter,
            pager: this.pager
        })
        this.navigator = Navigator()
        this.lifecycle = Lifecycle(this.loadOperation.execute)
    }
 
    // Other stuff that becomes observable

}
```

But now, in the typeScript I am forced to forward declare fields before initializing them,
so the `makeAutoObservable` already sees them when called and as a result I need to exclude them one by one:

```
class List {

    readonly notifier
    readonly apiClient
    readonly loadOperation
    readonly textFilter
    readonly showInactiveFilter
    readonly sorter
    readonly pager
    readonly orchestrator
    readonly navigator
    readonly lifecycle

    constructor(notifier: Notifier, apiClient: any) {
        makeAutoObservable(this, {
            notifier: false,
            apiClient: false,
            navigator: false,
            loadOperation: false,
            textFilter: false,
            showInactiveFilter: false,
            sorter: false,
            pager: false,
            orchestrator: false,
            lifecycle: false
        })

        this.notifier = notifier
        this.apiClient = apiClient
        this.loadOperation = LoadOperation(this.executeLoad, { onError: this.loadFailed })
        this.textFilter = TextFilter()
        this.showInactiveFilter = ShowInactiveFilter()
        this.sorter = Sorter()
        this.pager = Pager()
        this.orchestrator = Orchestrator({
            loadOperation: this.loadOperation,
            filters: [this.textFilter, this.showInactiveFilter],
            sorter: this.sorter,
            pager: this.pager
        })
        this.navigator = Navigator()
        this.lifecycle = Lifecycle(this.loadOperation.execute)
    }

    // Other stuff that becomes observable
}
```

Is there a way I could use `this.field = ...` in typeScript constructor without forward declaration (just like I did in javaScript)?

Is there any simpler way (other than one by one) to exclude those fields from observation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use their makeObservable-method instead, so instead of excluding everything you dont want, you include the things you actually want.

So lets say you want `notifier` to be an observable and not the rest:

```
makeObservable(this, {
    notifier: observable
})
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that one, just those included is usually even more than excluded...
I have tried enabling `declare` for the fields which should prevent emit of the fields before assignment, but babel was not cooperative.